# How would you overload an operator if you needed to multiply something like this example(0, 5, 0)* example(0,5,0) = 25

Tags: .net

How would you overload an operator if you needed to multiply something like this `example(0, 5, 0)* example(0,5,0) = 25`

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. Where does the 25 come from here? What does `example` store? (Is that a method, or did you mean to call `new Example(0, 5, 0)` in each case?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx), If I understand the question right.

```
public static Example operator +(Example c1, Example c2)
{ 
    return new Example() 
}
```